# rsync command pass password though script

Tags: linux, shell-script, ssh, rsync, perl

I am using following command

```
rsync -avze ssh myUser@REMOTE_SERVER:/REMOTE_PATH/ LOCAL_PATH
```

It's asking for password. Is it possible to pass password through any script? I do not want to use `ssh` keys.

Answer (score 1):

You have tagged your question with `perl` so...

Use [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Net::OpenSSH;

my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new(user => $user, password => $password);
$ssh->rsync_get({verbose => 1}, $remote_directory, $local_directory)
    or die $ssh->error;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that sshpass will do what you need:

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/noninteractive-shell-script-ssh-password-provider/

Comment: Please don't provide a link-only answer. It's better to summarise the relevant points here in case the other site goes away.